# Can I use "with" and "ranking" together here?

Tags: sentence-structure

I wrote the following sentence. And I am not sure is that correct in grammar to use “with” and “ranking” together here?

> "**With** a high GPA of xx/100 and **ranking** No.xx among xxx students, I am confident that I have xxx."

Comment: Yes, I would say your sentence there is fine!

Comment: OK, I understand. Thank you!

Comment: The sentence works, but "ranking" can be 1) a noun similar to "score", 2) a noun that is a gerund meaning "being ranked at", or 3) a present participle.  They are all very different.  "With" tends to work with all of them, but it is hard to understand all of the nuances - you might mean something slightly different than what you intend.  The difference between a gerund and a present participle is tricky.